# Xcode how to make flexible constraint in Autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

hello everyone I've get stuck in Auto-layout issues

I have login storyboard that contains three Items Image-view , Stack-view , Button like the first image below

I've tried to add constraints using two ways:

The first way I've added "pinned" constraint to Image-view as shown in  Photo1 below but when I've changed to landscape the Image was disappeared as the second  photo  below.
please notice I haven't got any warnings

The second Way I've tried by wrap the Image-view using view then i added 
"Pinned" constraint to view 
finally i added fixed width & height to Image-view and Horizontal & vertical in container but I've got this result  as third and fourth photo

what should i do  to make my Image-view Adaptive for all Screens ?

thanks

[Photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFwD7.png)
[Photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDJei.png)
[Photo3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlJ6a.png)
[Photo4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDaxd.png)

Comment: Could you please describe/show what your desired UI is for landscape? A potential route to consider is making the height of the image view a percentage of the height of the entire view, and then aspect ratio pinning the image view.

Comment: Thank for your replay

Comment: I want to show all items in landscape  with small size , is the aspect ratio pinning constraint  relative to screen's size in other words can i use it to add percentage size of item that what did you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As when changing to landscape screen **height** changing a lot. the problem with your design with Autolayout is it's not adaptive with landscape and portrait mode because you are give fixed **hight** and **width** to your layout.

to make your **image-view** Adaptive for all screens give your image-view **height** to **superview** **height** in **percentage** so when in landscape mode height will change your image-view will still gets the **height** from **superview height** in exact same **percentage**.

have a look at this demo hope this will help. 
[Autolayout](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13_aWKPiKS89dWLRTol9QXP6xPJ_UjgC8)

- First drop UIImageView into ViewController.
- Give it a top constraint and Align it horizontally to it's SuperView.
  As now it's only required height and width.
  [image]
- Then **Ctrl** drag from **ImageView** to **itself** and **select aspect ratio**. give
  a aspect **ration 1:1** (it's just telling **storyboard** if any of **height or
  width** is available i want the other to be the same like if **width** is
  given then **height** should be the same as **width**, vice versa for **height**) as you may want
  perfect square shape for your profile ImageView.
- Now **Ctrl** drag from **ImageView** to **SuperView** and select **Equal height**.

[image]

- As now your ImageView got the **height** to **SuperView Height**.
  give your ImageView **proportional height** (percentage, Aspect
  Ration or Multipiler) to **SuperView** how much you wanted to give like
  so.

[image]

[image]

**At the end your UIImageView will get the height proportional to SuperView height, vice versa for width.**

Comment: how can i add height in percentage for  image-view ?  Could you please write the steps to make it?
What difference between adding  height in percentage  and aspect ratio?

Comment: Aspect ratio is proportional relationship between the width of an image or any UI Element and its height like 1:2 and in simplified form(In percentage) it will be 50% it's up to you what you wanna choose.

Comment: I have edited the answer too have a look. If it does solved your problem please give it Up-vote, mark as answered and close the problem.

Comment: Thank you 
my problem solved  I appreciate your effort 
could you please give me references to learn more about aspect ratio  and Adaptive layout?
and what the difference between adding aspect ratio constraint “relative to super-view” vs  “relative to item itself” as I did for image-view
What dose  aspect ration 1:1 means ?

Comment: Can I use aspect ration constraint with stack-view?