# How to manage position imageView by Autolayout (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a simple imageView and i would like imageView to be aligned:

- Vertically/Horizontally. (I have already provided this values)
- I would like image to be proportionally the same on all devices and landscape mode. (Already done by vertical/horizontal alignment)
- **I want my imageView to increase/decrease with respect to frame(ipad/iphone)but proportionally to its own size. 64/64, 128/128, 256/256 and etc.**

Could you please assist me with respective constraints.

I have tried several ways, but it still now works properly.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look here it will work with any `UIElement` https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767311/8918347

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these 2 constraints

```
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.widthAnchor,
                         muliplier:0.5).isActive = true

imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

in IB

**1-**

Control drag from the imageView to the superView and from the popup select Equal widths , then click the constraint and change the multiplier to say 0.5 to make the image get half screen- width in any device ///// you can make it for the height if chooses Equal-heights

[image]

//

[image]

**2-**

Control-drag from the imageView to itself and select aspect ratio then change the multiplier to 1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could to define me the same thing but in IB? Like what actually this means? What constraints are these? Does this also make height to change?

Comment: to have aspect ratio constraint then you have to make either the width or the height proportional to screen

Comment: I have tried your way, and it works. But i am using stackview, it destroys size in landscape. Thanks. Will try to handle.